# cv2.HoughCircles when it doesn't find cycles

Tags: python, opencv

I'm detecting cycles in an image

[image: the a1.png]

and this is my code：

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('a1.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,80,
                        param1=50,param2=20,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when it can't find any circles in the image what will be happened? I think it will return null or none to circles. But i found errors

OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/opencv-U1UwfN/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482

And I want to keep the detection running all the time. So I use try catch like:

```
try:
   circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,80,
                            param1=50,param2=20,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

except :
    print("no cars!")
    exit()
else:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

but it still didn't work.
And I've tested if there are cycles which can be detected. it works.

So, how to adjust the parameters to find cycles? I've tried many parameters for the image. And I want to keep detecting when the program is running. Is it good to use try catch inside? or I should use something else

[image: this is the image can work]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the mistake. These's some spaces in the filename.

If it doesn't find cycles it will return this :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "circle.py", line 11, in 
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2789, in around
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 67, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 47, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

And it can use try catch to make the detecting keep on